# Recode multiple columns in loop by comparing with i with i+1

Tags: r, dplyr

I need once more help with a loop I can't get to work. This time, I have data like this:

```
> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  0  1  1  1  0
2  2  3  0  0  2
3  3  3  3  0  0
4  0  0  3  0  3
5  0  3  0  2  0
6  0  2  2  2  0
7  2  0  0  1  2
8  1  0  3  0  1
9  3  2  3  2  0
10 2  1  1  3  3
```

`dput(df)` is as follows

```
df <- structure(list(A1 = c(0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2), A2 = c(1, 
  3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1), A3 = c(1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 
  1), A4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3), A5 = c(0, 2, 0, 3, 
  0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(A1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), A2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), A3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), A4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector")), A5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
  "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to recode columns `A1:A4`, by comparing `A1` to `A2`, `A2` to `A3`,... The columns represent change over time, so the last column can't be compared, because it is the latest observation. A new observation is added every quarter, so this should be dynamic.
Hence, I thought of a loop with `ifelse` statements taking care of all possible transformations: `1` to `0`, `1` to `1`, `1` to `2`, `1` to `3`, ...

So I created empty columns  `columns_recoded`, where the results should go and tried the following for the first reclassification of  `columns_original`:

```
for (i in seq_along(columns_original)) {
  test = mutate(test, across(columns_recoded[i], ~ifelse(. == 1 & .[+1] == 1, "H_H", .)))
}
```

This works, but when I add the other conditions like this, I get error messages:

```
for (i in seq_along(columns_original)) {
  test = mutate(test, across(columns_recoded[i], ~ifelse(. == 1 & .[+1] == 1, "H_H",
ifelse(. == 1 & .[+1] == 2, "H_N",
ifelse(. == 1 & .[+1] == 3, "N_H",
ifelse(. == 1 & .[+1] == 0, "H_A", .))))))
}
```

I then tried to to it in several loops only with a single `ifelse` statement. Surprisingly, still only the first loop seems to do something. Only the first loop seems to be executed - the others have no more influence on my table.

I spent several hours on this now but I'm stuck - I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: It will probably be faster to make a transitional matrix, e.g. `temp` by pasting the cols 1:2, 2:3, 3:4 from `df`. You seem to have 16 possibilities for each: 0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, . . . 3 0, 3 1, 3 2, 3 3. Then translate the `temp` matrix to the final version by replacing "0 0", etc with your coding system. Your example shows only 4 of the 16 possibilities so it is not possible to show a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. And yes, my example shows only four possibilities - but I thought, a solution for this should be enough for me to extend it to all other possibilities.

Comment: Alternatively, I'd suggest pivoting the data to a long format - it would simplify things quite a bit. You'd have a single grouped operation instead of the loop.

Comment: I made it work with converting the table into longformat - much easier and no loops necessary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `tidyverse` already, try using a `case_when` statement, which is cleaner than all those `ifelse` and use the curly bracket syntax `"{<var_name>}"`with the glue `:=` assignment operator as shown the `mutate` below. This will allow you to dynamically create new variables as your dataset expands.

```
# generate vector of new column names   
new_cols <- paste0('d', seq(1, ncol(df) - 1))

# loop through existing df columns (ignore latest one)
for (i in (1:(ncol(df) - 1))) {
    df <- df %>%
        mutate("{new_cols[i]}" := case_when(df[, i] == 1 & df[, i + 1] == 1 ~ "H_H",
                                            df[, i] == 1 & df[, i + 1] == 2 ~ "H_N",
                                            df[, i] == 1 & df[, i + 1] == 3 ~ "N_H",
                                            df[, i] == 1 & df[, i + 1] == 0 ~ "H_A",
                                            TRUE ~ 'etc.') # continue with new statments as needed
               )
}
```

Check out the vignette at `?dplyr_data_masking` for more detail on masked variable evaluation in tidyverse.

Comment: Great solution - thanks! I got it working - as well as another solution by converting the table into long format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler approach in base R that avoids the loop (by using `sapply`) and the case statement. First construct a table of the codes you are using for different combinations:

```
mat <- matrix(" ? ", 4, 4)
mat[2, 1] <- "H_A"
mat[2, 4] <- "N_H"
mat[2, 3] <- "H_N"
mat[2, 2] <- "H_H"
mat
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
# [1,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
# [2,] "H_A" "H_H" "H_N" "N_H"
# [3,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
# [4,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
```

Notice that since R starts vector indices with 1, we need to add 1 to each value in `df` to identify the row and column of the table. Now we use the table to create the results:

```
result <- sapply(1:4, function(i) mat[cbind(df[, i]+1, df[, i+1]+1)])
result
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
#  [1,] " ? " "H_H" "H_H" "H_A"
#  [2,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [3,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [4,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [5,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [6,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [7,] " ? " " ? " " ? " "H_N"
#  [8,] "H_A" " ? " " ? " " ? "
#  [9,] " ? " " ? " " ? " " ? "
# [10,] " ? " "H_H" "N_H" " ? "
```